# Bukkit plugin ItemMeta always null

Tags: junit4, bukkit

I've spent hours looking at people who have this problem, but none of their solutions seem to work!

I'm trying to set the lore and display name of an ItemStacks ItemMeta.

Here's the code:

> ```
>   ItemStack is = new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_SWORD, 1);
>     ItemMeta meta = is.getItemMeta();
> ```

By running it (JUnit test), 1 error occurs. It's is.getItemMeta(), it's always null. How can it be null if I just made it?

Thank you for reading, I've been stumped for about an hour now :)

Comment: What do you mean by "run" it? Do you mean you export the JAR and put it in the servers /plugins dir? and then run the server (and not the Plugin Jar)?

Answer (score 2):

Kezz101's answer is mostly correct, but it *can* have an ItemMeta already. I would recommend:

```
Material mat = Material.DIAMOND_SWORD;
ItemStack is = new ItemStack(mat, 1);
ItemMeta  im = is.hasItemMeta() ?
    is.getItemMeta() : Bukkit.getItemFactory().getItemMeta(mat);
/* ...Do something with im... */
is.setItemMeta(im);
```

Answer (score 1):

'getItemMeta()' will return `null` if there is no meta to get. You need to create the meta first:

```
ItemMeta meta = Bukkit.getItemFactory().getItemMeta(Material.DIAMOND_SWORD);
```

Then you can manipulate the metadata. When you are done, just set it to the itemstack as so:

```
is.setItemMeta(meta);
```